CAPL Test Case for Monitoring CAN Signal Over Time
I'm trying to write a CAPL test case where I need to monitor a CAN signal BM_State under specific conditions for a duration of 7 seconds. The scenario is as follows:

I want to start monitoring when the signal BM_V exceeds 3.2.
After BM_V > 3.2, I need to check if within the next 3 seconds, the BM_State becomes 7.
Then, within the next 2 seconds (after BM_State becomes 7), I need to verify if BM_State changes to 9.
If these conditions are met, the test should pass.
Additionally, I would like to print the exact time when BM_State changed to 7 and 9, measuring the time from the moment when BM_V > 3.2.

How can I write this CAPL test case? i have tried several way with inbuilt function but not Succeed

Hard to tell what exactly your problems are, given the error "not Succeed".
The methods which enable you the verify signal values are (among others) testWaitForSignalInRange and testWaitForSignalMatch.
So in your case a simple sequence like this should do (depending on your use case, you should not use testWaitForSignalMatch but always use testWaitForSignalInRange because the signal may never be exactly 7):

// Wait for 10 seconds until BM_V is 3.2 or higher
retVal = testWaitForSignalInRange(BM_V, 3.2, 9999, 10000);
if(retVal < 1) {
  testStepFail("Signal did not raise above 3.2");
  return;
}
// store timestamp
startTime = timeNowInt64();

// Wait for at most 3 seconds for BM_V to become (exactly) 7
retVal = testWaitForSignalMatch(BM_V, 7, 3000);
if(retVal < 1) {
  testStepFail("Signal did not become 7 within 3 seconds");
  return;
}
testStep("ID", "BM_V changed to 7 after %d nano seconds", timeNowInt64() - startTime);

retVal = testWaitForSignalMatch(BM_V, 9, 2000);
if(retVal < 1) {
  testStepFail("Signal did not become 9 within 2 seconds");
  return;
}
testStep("ID", "BM_V changed to 9 after %d nano seconds", timeNowInt64() - startTime);

testStepPass();

